# Subdirectory Issue with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory, codeigniter-2

I have installed a CodeIgniter application on main domain (domain.com). Now I wanted to use a directory for a blog (domain.com/blog/) where I would like to install a WordPress powered blog. But the issue is that I created a Directory called a blog but when I try to access it by typing domain.com/blog/ I get CodeIgniter 404 not fount page. I am very new with CodeIgniter so I must be missing something here.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're using `.htaccess` to remove `index.php` from your URLs, you should have an `.htaccess` at the root of your project with something like this in it:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|css|images)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

It's basically saying "Send all requests to `index.php/$request` unless they start with `index.php`, `robots.txt`, `css`, or `images`".

This is so you don't have to use URLs like `http://example.com/index.php/controller/method`.

Just add `blog`:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|css|images|blog)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: but in case he has not used rewrite engine. he can just add a subdomain :)

Comment: The OP must be using mod_rewrite otherwise it wouldn't show a Codeigniter 404.

Comment: you can get 404 even when you are not using .htaccess - try it!!

Comment: It wouldn't load a *Codeigniter* 404 unless the request was routed to the Codeigniter bootstrap file, usually index.php. "Codeigniter 404" means the request was handled by CI and it didn't find a matching route or `show_404()` was called.

Comment: yes sure. but that does not mean that you should be using rewrite engine for it

Comment: What do you mean? How else could that happen?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22283/discussion-between-wesley-murch-and-mamdouh-alramadan)

Comment: Hi Wesley, That did the trick. mamdouh Wesley is right. I dont wanted to use subdomain as Search Engines considers it as different domain. :) Thanks a lot